# How can I run a script which sends customized bulk mails based on the date on spreadsheet if a date condition is met?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gmail

I am totally new to Google Sheet Apps Script. I have created two sheets, the first one of which includes name, emails and last contact date. The second one is email template that my script uses for sending personalized emails. I have successfully executed the code and my gmail has sent the personalized emails based on the template. So far I had no problem.

However, I want my script to send emails only to those whose last contact date is more than 9 months ago. I do not want to send anyone to whom I have not send emails within 9 months.

Also is it possible to update the last contact date when I run the script each time when each time the script sends emails?

I am so sorry if my question is a bit complicated. But I wanted to be clear as much as possible. Below is my script code that works well without date condition function. Thank you very much in advance for your time and help.

```
function sendEmail() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()

var sheet1=ss.getSheetByName('List');

var sheet2=ss.getSheetByName('Template');

var subject = sheet2.getRange(2,1).getValue();

var n=sheet1.getLastRow();

for (var i = 2; i < n+1 ; i++ ) {

var email = sheet1.getRange(i,3).getValue();

var firstName=sheet1.getRange(i,1).getValue();

var authorName=sheet1.getRange(i,4).getValue();

var bookTitle=sheet1.getRange(i,5).getValue();

var message = sheet2.getRange(2,2).getValue();

message=message.replace("<firstName>",firstName).replace("<authorName>",authorName).replace("<bookTitle>", bookTitle);

MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message);

}
```

I have just executed the script to send customized bulk emails based on data in sheets. But I do not know how I can create a date condition.

Here is the Google Sheet Link. Thank you so much.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1griuCXoN-dhU-kP_4tf0CS3BTdkOtsEaE4V4IiYhgYY/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
function sendEmail() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  var lsh = ss.getSheetByName('List');
  var tsh = ss.getSheetByName('Template');
  var subject = tsh.getRange(2, 1).getValue();
  var n = lsh.getLastRow();
  let dt = new Date();
  var dtv = new Date(dt.getFullYear(), dt.getMonth() - 9, dt.getDate()).valueOf()
  for (var i = 2; i < n + 1; i++) {
    let idt = new Date(tsh.getRange(i,?).getValue();//need column of date();
    const idtv = new Date(idt.valueOf());
    if (idtv < dtv) {
      var email = lsh.getRange(i, 3).getValue();
      var firstName = lsh.getRange(i, 1).getValue();
      var authorName = lsh.getRange(i, 4).getValue();
      var bookTitle = lsh.getRange(i, 5).getValue();
      var message = tsh.getRange(2, 2).getValue();
      message = message.replace("<firstName>", firstName).replace("<authorName>", authorName).replace("<bookTitle>", bookTitle);
      MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message);
      lsh.getRange(i,?).setValue(idt);//need column of date
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I cannot thank you enough for you help! Thank you very very much @Cooper . I inserted your code replacing "?" with the column number which is 6. However when I try to save and run the script, I receive an error code: "Syntax error: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list line: 10 file: Code.gs". Line 10 is the one that stars with "let idt = new Date"...   What can be the reason of that? I have just replaced question marks without changing anyhting. Can you help me about that? So sorry again I am totally a novice learner. Thank you again.

Comment: Thank you for the second revision @Cooper. I still receive another problem.                  It is TypeError: tsh.getValue is not a function Code.gs:10                                                                                                                                       Line 10 :   let idt = new Date(tsh.getValue(i,6));//need column of date();                    I think there is a type error with Line 10. I could not figure it out yet. Can you help me to fix that?

Comment: Thank you very much @Cooper. Now, the execution completed without any problem. However nothing happened. None of my emails did not receive any email. This was a template so I added my emails and I changed the dates. However, none of my emails did not get anything. I am giving a link to my google sheet.  Can you tell me what's wrong with the google sheet and the script? I am so sorry for taking your time. And I am very appreciated for your help.                                        [link]https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1griuCXoN-dhU-kP_4tf0CS3BTdkOtsEaE4V4IiYhgYY/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: It's time for you to begin learning how to debug your own code

Comment: Thanks a lot @Cooper. I found the problem and solved it. Thanks very much again.